# Strict Equality Comparison ( === ) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, equality

The `===` operator doesn't do the implicit type conversion, so even if the values are equal but are not of the same type `===` will simply return false.

During strict equality comparison, what operation is performed first? Like:

1. It checks data type of both left side operands & right side operands first

   `5 === '5'  // Return false as, number !== string` or
2. Compare both operands value first after that checks data type of both operands.

   `5 === 5  // Return true
   as, 5 === 5 (Both value is same)`

   Is now Data type will be checked?

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: It first does a  typecheck, if true then goes for comparison(==).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness):

> Strict equality compares two values for equality. Neither value is implicitly converted to some other value before being compared. **If the values have different types, the values are considered unequal. Otherwise, if the values have the same type and are not numbers, they're considered equal if they have the same value.** Finally, if both values are numbers, they're considered equal if they're both not NaN and are the same value, or if one is +0 and one is -0.

So, the `===` operator first checks the types, if they're equal, it checks their values. If the values are the same, it returns true, otherwise it returns false. If the types don't match, it returns false without checking the values at all.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first step of checking `===` is "Are the types of the operands the same?". If the answer is "no", no further checking happens and the result is `false`.
2. Secondly, if the types are same, it does exactly what `==` does, that means the values are checked for equality.